# How do I not Serialize an object if the object is empty

Tags: c#, xml

Is there a way to not Serialize an object if the object value is null?
My xml keeps having a lot of empty

```
<PersonName></PersonName>
```

(There is no other object with this value that it's serializing.)

Comment: What serializer do you use?

Comment: the normal System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer

Answer (score 0):

The `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer` by default skips null properties. So you don't have to do anything.
Obviously, you need to skip properties equal to `string.Empty`.

When using `XmlSerializer`, you can apply the `System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue` attribute to specify a value that will not be serialized.

For example, you have next class:

```
public class Person
{        
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue("")]
    public string PersonName { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

When using the following code

```
var person = new Person { Id = 1, PersonName = "", Age = 20 };

var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true };
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create("result.xml", settings))
{
    ser.Serialize(writer, person);
}
```

You will get this result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Person xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Id>1</Id>
  <Age>20</Age>
</Person>
```

But be careful: this attribute is not taken into account during deserialization. Therefore, from such XML you will get a `Person` class with the `PersonName` property equal to `null`.